# Access Request Approval Email Interception

Tags: 2013, content-approval

We are looking at the access request email notification in SharePoint 2013, and wondering how much customization we can do to it.

Is this something that "best practice...should not be customized", or do we have options on how to control what happens when someone approves or rejects a request?

Our scenario:

1. User asks for permissions
2. Site owner/SCA gets email notification
3. Site owner/SCA goes into approve or reject
4. If site owner/SCA does approve, we'd like to change how the email notification is then handled.  If rejected, we'd like the person that asked in bullet #1 to get notified.  If the site owner/SCA does in fact approve, we'd like the email going to person #1 to be PREVENTED, and get routed to a committee to decide what level of permissions are appropriate.

---

****Why are we asking about this?

We will have over 2TB worth of documents on our SharePoint site, and those that receive the email notification for access will in no way know who does/doesn't need access to all these documents.  If there are other avenues we should explore, please advise.

Thank you!